# What is the narrative type used in "Harry Potter" called?

Tags: terminology, j-k-rowling, harry-potter, narrator

Is there a name of the type of narrative used in J. K. Rowling's *Harry Potter* novels, where the events are written in third person but exclusively follow the perspective of Harry Potter? Only events that Harry experiences (or is told about) are written in the story, even down to feelings and emotions.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14016/4918 "Is there ever a point you aren't following Harry's perspective?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a story is told from a single character's point of view, this type of narrative is known as [third-person-limited narration](https://cla.purdue.edu/academic/english/theory/narratology/terms/limited.html) (see [Terms Used by Narratology and Film Theory](https://cla.purdue.edu/academic/english/theory/narratology/terms/) by Dino Franco Felluga, Pudue University). This type of narration can be contrasted with other [third-person narratives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narration#Third-person_voices), such as the omniscient third-person narration and the objective third-person narration. (Some sources use the term "subjective third-person narration" as an alternative to "third-person-limited narration.)

See also [Third-Person Limited: Analyzing Fiction's Most Flexible Point of View](https://www.writersdigest.com/write-better-fiction/why-third-person-limited-point-of-view) by Peter Mountford.